# inlining failed in call to always_inline '__m128i _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(__m128i)': target specific option mismatch _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i __X)

Tags: c++, compilation, sse

I am trying to compile [this project](https://github.com/norishigefukushima/WeightedJointBilateralFilter) from github which is implemented in C++ with SIMD intrinsic (SSE4.1). The project in github is given as a Visual Studio solution, but I am trying to port it in Qtcreator with cmake. While I am trying to compile it I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include/smmintrin.h:520:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '__m128i _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(__m128i)': target specific option mismatch
 _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i __X)
```

which I am sure it has to do with the SSE optimization part, but since I am not that familiar with this subject I do not really know what it means and how I can solve it and in the net that I searched I couldn't really get something useful. The code that gives the following problem is the following:

```
static void cvt8u32f(const Mat& src, Mat& dest, const float amp)
{
    const int imsize = src.size().area()/8;
    const int nn = src.size().area()- imsize*8 ;
    uchar* s = (uchar*)src.ptr(0);
    float* d = dest.ptr<float>(0);
    const __m128 mamp = _mm_set_ps1(amp);
    const __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for(int i=imsize;i--;)
    {
        __m128i s1 = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)s);

        _mm_store_ps(d,_mm_mul_ps(mamp,_mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(s1))));
        _mm_store_ps(d+4,_mm_mul_ps(mamp,_mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_srli_si128(s1,4)))));
        s+=8;
        d+=8;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<nn;i++)
    {
        *d = (float)*s * amp;
        s++,d++;
    }

}
```

can someone explain me what is the issue and what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *target specific option mismatch* seems to indicate that your (default?) compile target doesn't support SSE4.1. Perhaps [an `-mxxx` parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686638/whats-the-differrence-among-cflgs-sse-options-of-msse-msse2-mssse3-msse4) can persuade the compiler?

Comment: Yup, use `-msse4.1` for `pmovzx`.  That's the usual message for intrinsics that you haven't told the compiler the target supports.  That also tells the compiler it can use up to sse4.1 when auto-vectorizing.  If that's a problem (runtime CPU dispatching), then use separate compilation units.  Also  `-march=nehalem` would enable SSE4.2 support, and `-mpopcnt`.

Comment: thanks both indeed adding `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse4.1")` in the cmakelist seems that did the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW for me it maybe meant "make it not include xmmintrin.h file on accident"

Comment: Also, be aware that this message means your CPU might not support the instuctions, in which case you can still try to compile with -msse4.1 but you might not be able to run it afterwards.

Comment: using -mavx did it for me

Answer (score 6):

add in file.pro:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-msse3

Comment: `pmovzx` requires SSE4.1, so `-msse3` seems unlikely to help.

Comment: I also came across this problem just now. when I added `-madx` parameter, it is complied successfully.