# Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG / m128i _mm_shuffle_epi8 : target specific option mismatch

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans-8, dsa, botan

This is my first time trying `Botan`, so the strategy is to try get one thing work first, one at a time.

The first thing I'm doing is simply:

```
#include <botan/botan.h> 
class Myclass { 
    ... 
    Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng; 
}
```

All the `.h` files in the `/usr/local/include/botan` are working, but I have to add other `/usr/local/include/botan/internal/*.h` file there. Also all the `.cpp` files I have to add to the compile list one by one.

So now all the needed .cpp from the Botan lib seem to be complete, no more error about that. But this one last compile error seem to relate to the OS..??! and I'm completely lost with how to fix this..

```
In file included from /usr/local/src/botan/block/aes_ssse3/aes_ssse3.cpp:16:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/include/tmmintrin.h: In function ‘__m128i Botan::{anonymous}::aes_schedule_transform(__m128i, __m128i, __m128i)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/include/tmmintrin.h:136:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘__m128i _mm_shuffle_epi8(__m128i, __m128i)’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_shuffle_epi8 (__m128i __X, __m128i __Y)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/src/botan/block/aes_ssse3/aes_ssse3.cpp:62:24: note: called from here
    return _mm_xor_si128(
```

Anybody seen this before? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

I use `NetBeans IDE 8.1` on `fedora24`

Comment: Should had looked into the Botan Makefile 1st.. Adding -msse3 solved the problem. Also highly recommend: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772562/inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-m128i-mm-cvtepu8-epi32-m128i-t 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772562/inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-m128i-mm-cvtepu8-epi32-m128i-t

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-msse3` to the Makefile solved the problem. Recommend:

1. Ref the Botan Makefile
2. [inlining failed in call to always_inline '__m128i _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(__m128i)': target specific option mismatch _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i __X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772562/inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-m128i-mm-cvtepu8-epi32-m128i-t)
3. [Header files for x86 SIMD intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228855/header-files-for-simd-intrinsics)