Compilation Error using TBB: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’
I want to use the TBB library for my Project, but the compilation fails with this error:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/waitpkgintrin.h: In function ‘void tbb::detail::r1::prolonged_pause()’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/waitpkgintrin.h:53:1: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘unsigned char _tpause(unsigned int, long long unsigned int)’: target specific option mismatch
   53 | _tpause (unsigned int __A, unsigned long long __B)
      | ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.


I made a minimal reproducible setup were I still get this error:
CMake:
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    tbb
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB"
    GIT_TAG "v2021.2.3"
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(tbb)

add_executable(TestTbb test_tbb.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestTbb PUBLIC TBB::tbb )
target_include_directories(TestTbb PRIVATE ${tbb_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

test_tbb.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/concurrent_unordered_map.h>
int main(){
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, char> t;
    t.insert({1, 'a'});
    t.insert({2, 'b'});
    auto element = t.find(1);
    std::cout << "result for " << 1 << " = " << element->second << std::endl;
}


I'm using CLion with the WSL(Debian) Toolchain on Windows 11.
EDIT:
The answers to related Question inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_mullo_epi32’: target specific option mismatch
did not solve my Problem.

Probably related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587561/gcc-compilation-error-inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-even-after-set - it requires specific instruction set to be enabled and it should provide more info in error message after target specific option mismatch line what exactly it could not compile.

And SO automatically linked as related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128698/inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-mm-mullo-epi32-target-specific-opti - have you looked into that? it mentions you need to set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  and prossibly CMAKE_C_FLAGS for cmake

Yes smells that CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS are missing like maybe -mfpmath=sse  or  -mwaitpkg

@ÖöTiib thank you.
I added set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mwaitpkg") to the cmake file and now it compiled successfully.
