# Make - error: inlining failed in call to always_inline (Alpaca)

Tags: makefile, linux-mint, alpaca

I am trying to install Alpaca on my Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon. However when it comes to the Make part I get the following output

```
(base) ricc@ricc-K5:/mnt/Storage/software/dalai$ npx dalai alpaca install 7B --home /mnt/Storage/software/dalai
mkdir /mnt/Storage/software/dalai
{ method: 'install', callparams: [ '7B' ] }
mkdir /mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca
try fetching /mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca https://github.com/ItsPi3141/alpaca.cpp
[E] Pull TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')
    at new GitConfig (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:1604:30)
    at GitConfig.from (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:1627:12)
    at GitConfigManager.get (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:1750:22)
    at async _getConfig (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:5397:18)
    at async normalizeAuthorObject (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:5407:19)
    at async Object.pull (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:11682:20)
    at async Dalai.add (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/dalai/index.js:394:7)
    at async Dalai.install (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/dalai/index.js:346:5) {
  caller: 'git.pull'
}
try cloning /mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca https://github.com/ItsPi3141/alpaca.cpp
next alpaca [AsyncFunction: make]
exec: make in /mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca
make
exit
(base) ricc@ricc-K5:/mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca$ make
I llama.cpp build info: 
I UNAME_S:  Linux
I UNAME_P:  x86_64
I UNAME_M:  x86_64
I CFLAGS:   -I.              -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c11   -fPIC -pthread -mavx -msse3
I CXXFLAGS: -I. -I./examples -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -fPIC -pthread
I LDFLAGS:  
I CC:       cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
I CXX:      g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

cc  -I.              -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c11   -fPIC -pthread -mavx -msse3   -c ggml.c -o ggml.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
ggml.c: In function ‘ggml_vec_dot_f16’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1274:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1274 |             ay[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(y + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1273:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1273 |             ax[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(x + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1273:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1273 |             ax[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(x + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1274:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1274 |             ay[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(y + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1273:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1273 |             ax[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(x + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from ggml.c:155:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:52:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm256_cvtph_ps’: target specific option mismatch
   52 | _mm256_cvtph_ps (__m128i __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:911:33: note: called from here
  911 | #define GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(x)     _mm256_cvtph_ps(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(x)))
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:921:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD’
  921 | #define GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(p, i)     GGML_F32Cx8_LOAD(p)
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ggml.c:1274:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD’
 1274 |             ay[j] = GGML_F16_VEC_LOAD(y + i + j*GGML_F16_EPR, j);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:186: ggml.o] Errore 1
(base) ricc@ricc-K5:/mnt/Storage/software/dalai/alpaca$ exit
exit
ERROR Error: running 'make' failed
    at Alpaca.make (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/dalai/alpaca.js:51:15)
    at async Dalai.add (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/dalai/index.js:412:5)
    at async Dalai.install (/home/ricc/.npm/_npx/3c737cbb02d79cc9/node_modules/dalai/index.js:346:5)
```

I believe it's because of inappropriate/incomplete flags. However I have no expertise on this. This is the architecture specific Makefile part in which the problem probably lies. Any idea how to tweak it?

```
# Architecture specific
# TODO: probably these flags need to be tweaked on some architectures
#       feel free to update the Makefile for your architecture and send a pull request or issue
ifeq ($(UNAME_M),$(filter $(UNAME_M),x86_64 i686))
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
        CFLAGS += -mf16c
        AVX1_M := $(shell sysctl machdep.cpu.features)
        ifneq (,$(findstring FMA,$(AVX1_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mfma
        endif
        ifneq (,$(findstring AVX1.0,$(AVX1_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mavx
        endif
        AVX2_M := $(shell sysctl machdep.cpu.leaf7_features)
        ifneq (,$(findstring AVX2,$(AVX2_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mavx2
        endif
    else ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
        AVX1_M := $(shell grep "avx " /proc/cpuinfo)
        ifneq (,$(findstring avx,$(AVX1_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mavx
        endif
        AVX2_M := $(shell grep "avx2 " /proc/cpuinfo)
        ifneq (,$(findstring avx2,$(AVX2_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mavx2
        endif
        FMA_M := $(shell grep "fma " /proc/cpuinfo)
        ifneq (,$(findstring fma,$(FMA_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mfma
        endif
        F16C_M := $(shell grep "f16c " /proc/cpuinfo)
        ifneq (,$(findstring f16c,$(F16C_M)))
            CFLAGS += -mf16c
        endif
        SSE3_M := $(shell grep "sse3 " /proc/cpuinfo)
        ifneq (,$(findstring sse3,$(SSE3_M)))
            CFLAGS += -msse3
        endif
    else ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Haiku)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inlining failed in call to always\_inline ‘\_mm\_mullo\_epi32’: target specific option mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128698/inlining-failed-in-call-to-always-inline-mm-mullo-epi32-target-specific-opti)

Comment: It was a bit too complicated for me. In the end the problem relied on another file. They made a fix for it here https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/pull/563